# Unclear C++ syntax in operator overloading

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I'm still new to c++ and trying to understand the Expression Templates. I came across an example code on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates). I Understood most of the program and how it works but I'm not clear how these lines are interpreted by compiler:

```
 operator A&()             { return static_cast<      A&>(*this); }
 operator A const&() const { return static_cast<const A&>(*this); }
```

from the base expression template class below.
Usually the syntax of operator overloading is `return_datatype operator+ (args){body}` (e.g for + operator) but this gives errors and the ones in the function compiles without any error. Can anybody explain these two lines? What does `A&` and `A const&` before the operators do? And why `A& operator() (){}` and `A const& operator() (){}` doesn't work? It gives error:

```
no matching function for call to 'Vec::Vec(const Expr<Vec>&)'
   ExprSum(const Expr<A>& a, const Expr<B>& b): _u(a), _v(b) {}
```

-Pranav

The complete code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;


template <class A>
class Expr{
public:
  typedef std::vector<double>         container_type;
  typedef typename container_type::size_type   size_type;
  typedef typename container_type::value_type  value_type;
  typedef typename container_type::reference   reference;

  size_type size() const  {return static_cast<A const&>(*this).size(); }
  value_type operator [] (size_t i) const {return static_cast<A const&> (*this)[i];}
  operator A&()             { return static_cast<      A&>(*this); }
  operator A const&() const { return static_cast<const A&>(*this); }
};


class Vec : public Expr<Vec> {
private:
  container_type x;
public:
  Vec(){}
  Vec(size_type length) :x(length) {}
  size_type  size() const { return x.size(); }

  reference operator [] (size_type i){
    assert(i < x.size());
    return x[i];
  }
  value_type operator [] (size_type i) const {
    assert(i < x.size());
    return x[i];
  }

  template <class A>
  void operator = (const Expr<A>& ea){
    x.resize(ea.size());
    for(size_t i = 0; i < x.size(); i++){
      x[i] = ea[i];
    }
  }

};


template <class A, class B>
class ExprSum : public Expr <ExprSum <A,B> >{
private:
  A _u;
  B _v;
public:
  typedef Vec::size_type size_type;
  typedef Vec::value_type value_type;

  ExprSum(const Expr<A>& a, const Expr<B>& b): _u(a), _v(b) {}
  value_type operator [] (size_t i) const { return (_u[i] + _v[i]); }
  size_type size() const { return _u.size(); }
};


template <class A, class B>
ExprSum <A,B> const operator + (Expr<A> const& u, Expr<B> const& v){
  return ExprSum <A,B> (u,v);
}



int main(){

  size_t n = 10;
  Vec x(n);
  Vec y(n);
  Vec z;

  for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++){
    x[i] = i;
    y[i] = 2*i;
  }

  z = x + y;

  cout << z[7] << endl;

  cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: These are called conversion operators or cast operators. They are used to provide semantics for converting between distinct types. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator)

Comment: Instead of "doesn't work", explain what problem you are having

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [*conversion operator*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator). It looks similar to a normal overloaded operator, but it doesn't have a specified return type, and in place of the operator symbol you have the conversion target type.

Comment: Thanks @Sebastian for the pointing out its a conversion operator. The provided link indeed clarified my doubt. Thank you -Pranav